# Spring Gateway on localhost:8000

Tags: spring, routes, spring-cloud-gateway

Running a service on localhost:8000.  I route to it with Spring Gateway and only get a white page instead of the login page of the service.

I've tried routing using java, and also through a yml file.

### Java

```
    @SpringBootApplication
    public class GsGatewayApplication {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(GsGatewayApplication.class, args);
        }

        @Bean
        public RouteLocator myRoutes(RouteLocatorBuilder builder){
            return builder.routes()
                    .route(p->p
                    .path("/get")
                    .uri("localhost:8000/login"))
                    .build();
        }
    }
```

### application.yml

```
server:
  port: 8080
spring:
  application:
    name: api-gateway
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
      - id: weblogin
        uri: localhost:8000/login
        predicates:
        - Path=/get
```

I expect a login page, but get only a blank white page.

Answer (score 1):

By your configuration, when you access `localhost/get` you will be route to `localhost:8080/get`